# Prove the operator matrix is positive

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

[image]

The above lemma  is from Paulsen's book.

I have two questions:

1.The author set $A=\pi(a)$, we can view $\pi$ as a injective $*$-homomorphism, then $\|a\|=\|A\|\leq 1$, \begin{bmatrix} I& A\\ A^*& I\end{bmatrix} is positive , we only have \begin{bmatrix} I& \pi(a)\\ \pi(a)^*& I\end{bmatrix} is positive,
 how to prove that \begin{bmatrix} 1& a\\ a^*& 1\end{bmatrix} is positive?

2.If $\|A\|\geq 1$, how to conclude that there exist unit vectors $x$ and $y$ such that $\langle Ay,x \rangle <-1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M_2(A)$ is a unital subalgebra of $M_2(\mathbb B(\mathcal H))$, thus for any $x\in M_2(A)$, the spectrum is independent of the algebra, that is, $\sigma_{M_2(A)}(x)=\sigma_{M_2(\mathbb B(\mathcal H))}(x)$.  Since $\begin{bmatrix} 1& a\\ a^*& 1\end{bmatrix}$ is self-adjoint, and
$$\sigma_{M_2(A)}\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1& a\\ a^*& 1\end{bmatrix}\right)=\sigma_{M_2(\mathbb B(\mathcal H))}\left(\begin{bmatrix} I& \pi(a)\\ \pi(a)^*& I\end{bmatrix}\right)\subset[0,\infty),$$
it follows that $\begin{bmatrix} 1& a\\ a^*& 1\end{bmatrix}$ is positive.

For your second question, Since $\|A\|>1$, there exists $y\in\mathcal H$ with $\|y\|=1$ such that $\|Ay\|>1$.  Letting $x_0=\frac{1}{\|Ay\|}Ay$, we have 
$$\langle Ay,x_0\rangle=\|Ay\|>1.$$
Now let $x=-x_0$.  Then
$$\langle Ay,x\rangle=-\langle Ay,x_0\rangle<-1.$$

Comment: Thank you so much. May I ask you aome personal questions: Are you a professor? What is your research interest?

Comment: I'm a graduate student, with interests in Operator algebras, $K$-theory, and noncommutative geometry.

Comment: Would you mind recommending some books about your reseach field? If you don't mind, can you list some open problems about your reaseach area? I find I can concentrate on reading with questions.

Comment: For operator algebras, an introductory book I always recommend is "$C^*$-Algebras and Operator Theory"  by Murphy.  After that, there are several options to consider.  For $K$-theory, I'd recommend Rordam, Larsen, and Lastsen's book "An Introduction to $K$-Theory for $C^*$-algebras".  As for noncommutative geometry, there aren't really any phenomenal books out there, but perhaps my favorite introduction to the subject is "Analytic $K$-Homology" by Higson and Roe.

Comment: Thanks very much. Do there exist reference books about UCT class. I found many good journals like to publish papers involving UCT class.